# A song that plays in Tokyo Ghoul:re episode 10 on 1:30

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the song that plays in *Tokyo Ghoul:re* episode 10 on 1:30?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official ost, or at least i dont think so, but this is as close as i can get: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1Qxdt0qi6U
hopefully its close enough

Comment: Looks like the YouTube link is dead...